# Pycharm SSH remote interpreter: editor doesn't recognize module

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, root-framework, pyroot

I'm currently trying to get PyCharm running with a remote interpreter via SSH.

The connection itself is working well, however one of my imported modules "ROOT" is not recognized by the editor ("No module named ROOT" at the "import ROOT" statement).

Before "ROOT" can be imported in any python session (while using the Terminal and not PyCharm), a "thisroot.sh" file with environment variables etc. has to be called. Thus, it's sourced at every ssh login with aid of the .bash_profile/.bashrc file.
Therefore, if the .sh file is not sourced before starting python in a SSH terminal, python cannot find the module.

Hence, I think the problem is that PyCharm doesn't call the .bashrc file (and thus doesn't source the "thisroot.sh" file) after establishing a connection. If I open a remote Python console directly in PyCharm, the "ROOT" module is not found as well.

For a less complicated module, one could add the environment variables by hand into the PyCharm settings. For my module however, it's not really feasible.

Is there any way such that PyCharm recognizes the module in the editor (and finds it in the remote Python console)? I've tried sourcing the "thisroot" file with the PyCharm StartUp script settings, but it didn't work till now.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with pycharm. this post solved my problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/684550/importing-a-python-module-works-from-command-line-but-not-from-pycharm